# PHP7.4 and firebird/interbase: ibase_connect(), ibase_query() Call to undefined function

Tags: php, firebird, pecl, interbase, php-7.4

I'm dealing with a legacy firebird database and can't seem to get it to work with PHP7.4.
The interbase extension isn't available anymore in PHP7.4, I can only install PDO_FIREBIRD.

There are also no releases on PECL.
https://pecl.php.net/package/interbase

Any hints how to make it work with 7.4?

Comment: Visit https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/php-firebird  and https://firebirdsql.org/en/php-driver/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of PHP indeed no longer ship with the interbase package. Instead you can use the [Firebird PHP driver](https://firebirdsql.org/en/php-driver/), which is a fork and continued development of the interbase package.

Comment: A couple of minutes after posting the question I found the php driver and it does work as intended.

Comment: I have the same problem with php 7.4 and firebird. I have downloaded the drivers that you indicate, but I don't know how I have to use them. I have added them to the / php / ext folder and added to the php.ini as extension = php_interbase.dll, but it still doesn't work. However, with php 7.3 it works perfectly.

Comment: @Mimmetico I recommend asking about this on https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-php

Answer (score 1):

Well, I faced some caveats while dealing with legacy Firebird data structures.

To put it simply, I had to address two broad issues:

**1 - Match client libraries with dataset On-disk Structure (ODS)**

Each Firebird version supports a limited range of On-Disk Structures (ODSs). The following link has a pretty nice reference on this topic:

https://ib-aid.com/en/articles/all-firebird-and-interbase-on-disk-structure-ods-versions

ADODB and PHP PDO are abstraction layers to client libraries in the host system. And PHP 7.4 supports *only* FB 3.0 and later clients. So, it is necessary to match the abstraction layer with the client library available.

For datasets up to FB 2.5:

- disk structure should be up to ODS 11;
- client version should be up to FB 2.5.9 (recommended);
- PHP engine should be up to 7.3 (7.1 already has issues);
- legacy functions `ibase_` and `fbird_` should work fine;
- ADODB, PHP PDO, etc. should *not* work.

For datasets starting from FB 3.0:

- disk structure should be ODS 12 or higher;
- client version should be FB 3.0 or higher;
- PHP engine should be 7.4 or higher;
- legacy functions `ibase_` and `fbird_` should *not* work;
- ADODB, PDO etc. should work fine.

**2 - Match client and server platforms and params**

For any client and server combination:

- the client and the server should share the same platform, 32 or 64 bits;
- the connection should use SQL dialect 1 or 3, depending on legacy dataset usage;
- the character encoding should be WIN-1251 (legacy) or UTF-8 (new default).

**Opinion**

In my experience, it is difficult to "force" legacy FB connections into an up-to-date PHP engine. I suppose it is more challenging with Linux systems because `libgcc` has different entry points from versions 5 to 6 (I guess...), and `musl` just ain't supported.

Things are more flexible in Windows since `fbclient.dll` is the only client library needed for the connection, and it depends on Win32 libraries that have maintained the same entry points over the years.

I'd recommend upgrading the dataset to Firebird 4 and using updated extensions and clients. However, if this is not an option, downgrading should be streamlined from the host OS, through the PHP engine, until the FB client.

Unfortunately, I believe "this is the way."

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have problems connecting firebird with php. I went through many questions until I discovered that there has to be 3 dll's inside the apache bin folder. gds32.dll
msvcr71.dll
fbclient.dll.

Without these dll's it doesn't work, for some unknown reason the new version of xampp came missing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can connect to VERY old Firebird DB from PHP 8. My case was Interbase 7.0 as server + (PHP 8.1 + Windows Server 2019) as client.

To do this, use:

1. Default php_pdo_firebird.dll, shipped with php is ok. Just uncomment in php.ini
2. Download OLD Firebird server.
   http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/discontinued-versions/
   In my case I used v. 2.1.
   Download .zip version, 32 / 64 bit - the same as your php, apache...
3. Extract zip file, in bin folder there is instclient utility. It adds fbclient.dll and gds32.dll to system folder.
   just call from cmd (as Administrator):

instclient i f

instclient i g

after that you can check if it is installed correctly:

instclient q f

instclient q g

4. add to services file (%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\services.):
   gds_db 3050/tcp
5. Restart Apache, PHP should be able to call like:

$dsn = "firebird:dbname=111.111.111.111:C:/aaaa/bbbb.GDB;"

$conn =  new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).