# PHP 7.4 with Firebird Interbase

Tags: php, firebird, php-7.4, interbase

Referring to the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483052/php7-4-and-firebird-interbase-ibase-connect-ibase-query-call-to-undefined), it seems that PHP 7.4 does not support php_interbase anymore. However, I read that Firebird has released PHP Driver. How can I install so that my PHP 7.4 can still support php_interbase or something similar. I tried to search for it but still can't find any solution.

Comment: I don't normally use PHP, but shouldn't it just be a matter of downloading the driver from https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/php-driver/, and putting it in your extension directory, or alternatively, build it yourself following the instructions on https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/php-firebird? If that is not enough, I highly recommend that you create an issue on https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/php-firebird/issues and ask for installation instructions to be documented (beyond the _"Copy the file to your php extension dir and restart your webserver."_ currently in the readme).

Comment: You could also ask your question on https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-php